# Clear intent when navigating from activity B to activity A

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, android-lifecycle

I get an intent when I am in my main activity,

```
if (getIntent() != null &&
            LinkReceiver.LINK_INTENT.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Uri appLinkData = getIntent().getData();
        if (appLinkData != null) {
            processIntent(appLinkData);
        }
    }
```

I have this in the `onStart` method. I use `startActivity()` to navigate to `another activity`. When I press back on the second activity that I am on, I return back to the `main activity`, but the intent never becomes null.

I have tried doing `setIntent(null)` in the `processIntent` method, I have tried doing `getIntent.setAction("")` and `getIntent.setData(null)`.

Is there any way to do this without overriding the `onBackPressed()` method in the second activity to open the main activity again without an intent.

Comment: Intent will never be null , you are coming from any activity to your main_activity right , send some parameters with your Intent and then check the value of that parameter and do your respective action.

Comment: The intent is sent from a website as a deep link. I don't have much control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIntent()` will always return the `Intent` that the `Activity` was launched with. Why not just set a flag in your `MainActivity` when you call `startActivity()` for the other `Activity`. When it returns to your `Activity` you can check the flag to determine the state and act accordingly.

Alternatively you can use `startActivityForResult()` which will allow you to pass information back from the `Activity` you launched. Also the method `onActivityResult()` will get called on your `MainActivity` when the other `Activity` completes, so you can set internal flags or whatever to determine what to do next.